# Leaflet JS zoomend event is not triggering when zoomed out too much

Tags: leaflet

I initialise the map with a zoomlevel of 15:

```
map.setView(latlng, 15)
```

at some point later when the user interacts with a button that triggers this function:

```
const zoomInAndTrigger = () => {
  map.setView(latlng, 18)

  map.once("zoomend", () => {
    // some triggers fired
  })
}

zoomInAndTrigger() // on button click
```

this works perfectly fine. 
Well, unless the user zooms the map out more than the initial `15` zoomlevel before he triggers the `zoomInAndTrigger`, then the `'zoomend'` is not triggered at all.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

When zooming from level e.g. 14 to 18 the zoom animation is not played by default - the default value for the map's `zoomAnimationThreshold` is 4, and [quoting from the Leaflet reference](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-zoomanimationthreshold%60):

> Won't animate zoom if the zoom difference exceeds this value.

The whole zoom interaction then executes instantly, before your `map.once("zoomend", ...` line has executed.

As a rule of thumb, you should *always* attach event handlers *before* running code that triggers that event, no matter if you've only observed the event happening some time after. It will armor you against some [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

On the other hand, you can pass a set of [zoom/pan options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#zoom/pan-options) to the [`setZoom`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-setzoom) call; the [`animate` zoom option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#zoom-options) can forcibly enable or disable zoom animation for any given zoom operation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to attach your "zoomend" event listener *before* executing the map setView.

By default, when the zoom levels gap is too big, or the new position too far, Leaflet setView will instantly reset the view instead of animating the view change. Then your listener is attached *after* the view has already changed, and it is not triggered.